# Некорректное отображение текста, запрошенного php из бд под phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Изучаю бд и php, столкнулся с проблемой. Вот код.

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "mybase");
if ($connection == false) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к бд mybase № " . $connection>connect_errno . " " . $connection->connect_error;
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]}
$raw = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `articles_category`");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($raw);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Вот результат

Array ( [ID] => 1 [Title] => РЎРїРѕСЂС‚ )

А хотелось бы получить первый элемент таблицы articles_category - Спорт.

Настройки кодировок:

Сам файл php (работаю через phpstorm) в utf-8

OpenServer http - utf-8, MySQL - utf8_general_ci

Таблицы в phpmyAdmin через utf8_general_ci

Comment: <?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>

Comment: Решено. А почему так?

Comment: Потому, что если хочешь корректно работать с utf-8 - сохраняешь код в utf-8 и прописываешь его в заголовок

Comment: иначе у тебя страница в кодировке по-умолчанию, а вывести ты на неё пытаешься в utf-8, потому видишь не то, что хотелось бы

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно после коннекта нужно указать базе в какой кодировке ей работать: `mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");`

Comment: Попробовал запрос к connection, результат отрицательный. Подгуглил про mysql_set_charset, воткнул utf-8, результат тот же

Answer (score 0):

в htacess  добавьте так

```
DefaultLanguage ru
AddDefaultCharset utf8
php_value default_charset "utf8"
```